# TeamCity build agent becomes disconnected after adding self-signed https certificate to teamcity

Tags: security, https, teamcity, teamcity-7.0, build-agent

I added a self-signed certificate to my Teamcity BuildServer to introduce https support so that it can now be accessed at

```
https://ServerUrl:8443
```

(More details about how [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration) )

The result was that I was able access the server via https, but my build agent was now disconnected. How to fix this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The build agent works as a client to the build server and communicates with it using http/https, and it turns out that when you add a self-signed certificate the build agent does not accept it.

I needed to

1. Let the build agent know the new path for communicating with the server
2. Let the build agent know that it could trust the self-signed certificate

To change the path I did the following  (see [this post](http://earlyandoften.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/teamcity-port/) for more details )

> Locate the file:
>  
>   **$TEAMCITY_HOME/buildAgent/conf/buildAgent.properties** 
>   Change the property
>  
>   **serverUrl=http:\://localhost\:8080** to your new url

To let the build agent know that it could trust the new certificate I had to import it into the build agent's key store.This was done using keytool:

```
keytool -importcert -file <cert file>  
        -keystore <agent installation path>/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

( *unless you've changed it, the keystore is protected by password: changeit*)

The TeamCity team describes this process in slightly more details [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Using+HTTPS+to+access+TeamCity+server)

**NOTE**
*If you need to retrieve your certificate from the TeamCity buildserver keystore, you can also use keytool to do this* :

```
keytool -export -alias <alias name>  
        -file <certificate file name> 
        -keystore <Teamcity keystore path>
```

Comment: I didn't have to do step 2 for some reason... step 1 was enough on TC9.

Comment: When I originally wrote this post, we were working with TC7 (I have added the TC version tag to the original question)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [link](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Using+HTTPS+to+access+TeamCity+server) to the TeamCity v8 documentation on the keytool.

I was doing this on a Windows Build Agent and had a self-signed SSL cert on my Amazon Linux Build Server. Here were the steps I took:

1. Went to build server in browser on Build Agent i.e. https://teamcity.example.com
2. Clicked on the certificate error in the URL and downloaded the cert to the local machine
3. Exported the certificate from the certificate explorer in windows into a cer file.
4. Used the keytool exactly as specified in the documentation

   ```
   > keytool -importcert -file <cert file where it was exported to> 
     -keystore <path to JRE installation>/lib/security/cacerts
   password: changeit
   ```
5. Restarted the build agent and viola!